# How to remove colour scale legend from plot() of spp density in R

Tags: r, image, plot, legend, spp

I am plotting the density of a two-dimensional, weighted spatial point pattern. I'd like to make the plot without a colour scale legend, and save it with no (or minimal) boarders on all sides, like this:[image: like this] My problem is that I can't remove the colour scale legend. Reproducible code below:

```
## Install libraries:
library(spatstat) #spatial package
library(RColorBrewer) #create custom colour ramps

## Create reproducible data:
data <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = 50))
x <- c("x", "y", "weight")
colnames(data) <- x
data$x <- runif(50, 0, 20)
data$y <- runif(50, 0, 20)
data$weight <- sample(1:200, 50)

## Set plotting window and colours:
plot.win <- owin(c(0,20), c(0,20)) # plot window as 20x20m
spat.bat.frame <- NULL # create a frame to store values in
cols1<-colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(9,"Blues"))(100) #define colour ramp for density plots

## Create and save plots:
jpeg(filename = "Bad plot.jpeg", res = 300, units = "cm", width = 20, height = 20)
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0),oma=c(0,0,0,0),lwd=1)

ppp_01 <- ppp(x = data$x, y = data$y, window = plot.win)
ppp_02 <- ppp(x = data$x, y = data$y, window = plot.win)
plot(density(ppp_01, weights = data$weights), main=NULL, col=cols1, sigma = 1)
plot(ppp_02, add=TRUE) #add spp points to density plot

dev.off()
```

I've tried legend=FALSE, auto.key=FALSE, colorkey=FALSE, which don't seem to be compatible with plot() (i.e. they don't give an error but don't change anything). I've also tried some work-arounds like saving a cropped image with dev.off.crop() or by adjusting margins with par(), but haven't been able to completely remove the legend. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to remove a colour scale legend of a density spp (real-valued pixel image) using plot()?

I specifically need to plot the density of the spatial point pattern, to specify a custom colour ramp, and to overlay the spp points onto the density image. I could try plotting with spplot() instead, but I'm not sure this will allow for these three things, and I feel like I'm missing a simple fix with plot(). I can't crop the figures manually after saving from R because there are 800 of them, and I need them all to be exactly the same size and in the exact same position.

Thank you!

Comment: Try `ribbon=FALSE` on the density plot.

Comment: Yes! This worked, thank you. If anyone finds this in the future: density() was creating an object of type im. Look up ?plot.im to find the solution, ribbon=F

Answer (score 0):

Since `plot` is a generic function, the options available for controlling the plot will depend on the class of object that is being plotted. You want to plot the result of `density(ppp_01, weights = data$weights)`. Let's call this `Z`:

```
Z <- density(ppp_01, weights = data$weights, sigma=1)
```

*Note:  the smoothing bandwidth `sigma` should be given inside the call to `density`*

To find out about `Z`, you can just print it, or type `class(Z)`.
The result is that `Z` is an object of class`"im"` (pixel image).

So you need to look up the help file for `plot.im`, the plot method for class `"im"`. Typing `?plot.im` shows that there is an argument `ribbon` that controls whether or not the colour ribbon is displayed. Simply set `ribbon=FALSE` in the call to `plot`:

```
plot(Z, ribbon=FALSE, main="", col=cols1)
```

Or in your original code

```
plot(density(ppp_01, weights=data$weights, sigma=1), main="", col=cols1)
```

However I strongly recommend separating this into two lines, one which creates the image object, and one which plots the image. This makes it much easier to spot mistakes like the misplacement of the `sigma` argument.